# facebook likes that WE have done

Tags: facebook

We have several people working on our Facebook page, and I am trying to find out if there is a way to list all the companies that WE have liked - not the ones that like us.

I know that isn't possible to do (apart from analytic data). We are a chamber of commerce, and we were liking all our members who are on Facebook, hoping to be able to look back and find out how many are actually on Facebook.

Hope this makes sense, and I hope it is possible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure just go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer (you must be a registered facebook developer to acces this tool).

Then on the input where you have this:

`your_fb_id?fields=id,name`

change it to this

`your_fb_id?fields=id,name,accounts` and press send.

You'll get all the pages wich you're administrator, choose the one you want by clicking on the respective ID. Now you're querying the page you've chosen. Last step, on the input to make queries change it to this:

```
your_page_id?fields=likes
```

**EDIT**

The previous request only returned the number of total likes made by the page.

To get the likes made by the page on other pages you have to use **FQL Query**

Change from **Graph API** to **FQL Query** and paste this

```
SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = your_PAGE_ID)
```

This is without doing any code, if you want to get the information and format it on your own way, you'll have to develop an app where you grant the permission manage_pages and user_likes(this one I don't think is mandatory though), use the graph api to get the likes and format the json returned data

Comment: Thanks for this, it gives me a numerical response, should it be giving me a list of names that we have liked? I want to cross reference the names to people who are members to get a picture of how many of our members are on facebook.

Comment: excellent! Thank you! I looked into that data table - it gives ID numbers but doesn't store the company names, is that right?

Comment: yes that's right, but if you need the company names just change the query to this SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = your_PAGE_ID)

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you so much, it is just what I needed, and way beyond my abilities to create myself. Thank you!

Comment: glad I could help you out, I've updated my answer with the query that returns the name for future visitors. Good luck with that